# On the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

My homework asks me to calculate (if it exists) the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{(1+(-1)^n)^n}{n}}$$

My thinking is: $(-1)^n$ would, as we all know, oscillate between 1 and -1, meaning that $(1+(-1)^n)$ would be either $0$ or $2$. Thus, for all odd cases:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{0^n}{n}}=0$$
And then, for all even cases:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{2^n}{n}}$$
Using Cauchy:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{^n\sqrt{\frac{2^n}{n}}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{^n\sqrt{2^n}}{^n\sqrt{n}}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{2}{1}} = 2$$

And then, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{2^n}{n}} = \infty$$
Which means that our original expression... has no limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The sequence does not have a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Set $a_n=\frac{(1+(-1)^n)^n}{n}$

Observe that

$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m)=\infty$

and

$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\inf_{m\geq n}a_m)=0$.

Since $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n \neq\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$, the limit of the sequence does not exist.